# Image Matrix Vector Representation for the Degradation Model

Tags: image-processing, matlab, linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the the degradation model equation but I have doubt that how come y^t.x.h will be equal to  x^t.h^t.y . Aren't they transpose of each other.

[image]

Comment: Could you please review my answer and mark it?

Answer (score 2):

Here the quantity $y^T H x$ is a real scalar (corresponding to an energy). And scalars can also be considered as  matrices of dimension $1  \times 1$. Such matrices are equal to their transpose.

When you have a product of matrices that ends up in a scalar, one often derives results using the associativity of the matrix products, and the property of transposition: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. Steps by steps, you have:

$$(y^T H x)^T = (y^T (H x))^T =  (H x)^T (y^T)^T= x^TH^T(y^T)^T $$

thus

$$(y^T H x)^T = x^TH^Ty\,.$$

Warning: when you have complex quantities, you have to play with complex conjugate has well.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent Duval

Comment: I have added a couple of intermediate computations, please tell me whether is it useful

Answer (score 1):

Indeed since both expressions are scalars then they are equal to each other since the transpose of a scalar is the same scalar.

See in MATLAB as an example (Calculating $ {x}^{T} H y $ and $ {y}^{T} {H}^{T} x $):

```
>> vX = randn(10, 1);
>> vY = randn(10, 1);
>> mH = randn(10, 10);
>> vX.' * mH.' * vY

ans = -0.8618

>> vY.' * mH * vX

ans = -0.8618
```

As you can see, indeed both expressions are scalars.
As expected $ {x}^{T} H y = {\left( {x}^{T} H y \right)}^{T} = {y}^{T} {H}^{T} x $.